# How to use multithreading on slurm cluster with snakemake?

Tags: multithreading, cluster-computing, slurm, snakemake

I understand how to tell snakemake to use multiple threads for a given rule using the `threads` directive, and have a Snakefile that specifies a rule using multiple threads. If I run snakemake directly on a cluster, e.g. `snakemake --cores 10 -n`, then the output correctly says that the rule in question will use 10 threads. From this I can conclude that my rule syntax is correct within the Snakefile. However, if I instead submit the pipeline to a Slurm cluster scheduler, i.e. `snakemake --profile slurm/config.yaml -n`, then the output shows that the rule will only use a maximum of 1 threads. So, am I missing some slurm parameter in my config file? From what I could find, it sounds like this should be taken care of with `--cpus-per-task {threads}`, however this is  not accomplishing what I want.

Here is the Snakefile rule:

```
rule bwa_map:
    input:
        fa="data/ref.fa"
        ind="data/ref.fa.bwt"
        r1="data/{sample}_R1.fastq.gz"
        r2="data/{sample}_R2.fastq.gz"
    output:
        "mapped_reads/{sample}.bam"
    shell:
        "bwa mem -t 2 {input.fa} {input.r1} {input.r2} | samtools view -b - > {output}"
```

And here is my `config.yaml` file below:

```
cluster: "sbatch --parsable -p high2 --time={resources.runtime} --mem={resources.mem_mb} --job-name={rule}.{wildcards} -o snake_logs/{rule}.{wildcards}.%j.out -e snake_logs/{rule}.{wildcards}.%j.err --cpus-per-task {threads}"
```

Comment: Your general idea sounds right. Can you share your `Snakefile` or a MWE? `snakemake --cores 10 -n` showing `threads: 10` is not necessarily an indication, that your syntax is correct (Your syntax could be incorrect and snakemake simply assigning the `--cores 10` to the rule). Note also that `snakemake --cores 10 -n` runs on your login/head node, while `snakemake --profile ...` submits to the cluster manager; does your targeted partition have sufficient resources assigned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `threads: 10` to your rule, else `Snakemake` doesn't have a value to propagate for the rule to `sbatch`:

```py
rule bwa_map:
    input:
        fa="data/ref.fa"
        ind="data/ref.fa.bwt"
        r1="data/{sample}_R1.fastq.gz"
        r2="data/{sample}_R2.fastq.gz"
    output:
        "mapped_reads/{sample}.bam"
    threads: 10
    shell:
        "bwa mem -t 2 {input.fa} {input.r1} {input.r2} | samtools view -b - > {output}"
```

Comment: Thanks, for pointing that out - actually I did have `threads` in the rule but the problem still persisted

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that when the `threads` directive is specified within the rule, running dry-run mode, i.e. `snakemake -n` does not show the correct specified number of threads in the output for me. However, running snakemake not in dry-run mode then shows the correct number of threads once the job starts running.

Comment: That is unexpected. If you can reproduce this behaviour in an MWE, it would be worthwhile to create a bug report over in [Snakemake's GitHub repo](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake)

Comment: I also encountered this discrepancy in {threads} with dry-run using Snakemake = 7.28.3. Threads always shows 1 during dry-run, but then the correct value in a real run.