# Snakemake ignores custom number of threads

Tags: python, snakemake

For all of my rules in my snakefile, `snakemake` ignores the number of threads that I set:

```
rule trim:
    input:
        r1="reads/{sample}_R1.fastq.gz",
        r2="reads/{sample}_R2.fastq.gz",
    output:
        multiext("trimmed/{sample}", 
            "_val_1.fq.gz",
            "_R1.fastq.gz_trimming_report.txt",
            "_val_2.fq.gz",
            "_R2.fastq.gz_trimming_report.txt",),
    threads: config["resources"]["trim"]["cpu"]
    resources:
        runtime=config["resources"]["trim"]["time"]
    conda:
        "envs/read-processing.yaml"
    log:
        "logs/trim_galore/{sample}.log",
    shell:
        "trim_galore -j {threads} -q 20 --basename {wildcards.sample} "
        "-o trimmed --paired {input.r1} {input.r2} 2> {log}"
```

When I run a dry run I get this for the shell command:

```
trim_galore -j 1 -q 20 --basename control_2_input_hyp -o trimmed --paired reads/control_2_input_hyp_R1.fastq.gz reads/control_2_input_hyp_R2.fastq.gz 2> logs/trim_galore/control_2_input_hyp.log
```

The `-j` flag is the number of threads to use and should be 8, as set in `config`. Even when I change `config["resources"]["trim"]["cpu"]` to 8, it still sets `-j` to 1, and this happens for all my rules.

Why does `snakemake` only use one thread?

I am using version `snakemake` 7.32.3.

Comment: Potentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76448109/11318472 Did you try running snakemake in non-dry-run mode?

Comment: Yes thank you. In the non-dry mode it applied the correct number of threads! I thought I was going crazy. Hopefully they can fix this at some point.

Comment: I don't think there was ever a bug report on it... Just opened one, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with `snakemake` when using `--dry-run`. Without `--dry-run` the right number of `threads` should be reported, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76448109/11318472

I've opened a bug report on [GitHub](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/2430), feel invite to add details there.